# Vault SSH PKI with OIDC - user as SSH principal

Tags: openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

My configuration so far is working fine. Users can login to Vault Web interface using OIDC (linked to Azure AD). AD Groups are transmitted to Vault as well. So I can assign AD Groups to Vault Policies. A User who is signed in to Vault is able to sign a SSH Public Key. So far so good...

The only missing piece is Identity propagation. I want to be able to trace users on my SSH Hosts. As such, I need to add the username to the SSH Certificate.

Therefore, when a user signs her SSH public key, I want to add her Username (email, full name, anything that relates her real identity) as a principal to the SSH Certificate.

If I understood correctly, my issue is similar to [this one](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/pull/7548), but instead of userpass secret engine, I use OIDC.

I tried to adopt the code as suggested in the git-issue:

```
cat <<EOF > signer-clientrole.hcl
{
    "allow_user_certificates": true,
    "allowed_users": "root,{{identity.entity.aliases.$(vault auth list -format=json | jq -r '.["oidc/"].accessor').name}}",
    "default_user": "",
    "allow_user_key_ids": "false",
    "default_extensions": [
        {
          "permit-pty": ""
        }
    ],
    "key_type": "ca",
    "ttl": "60m0s"
}
EOF
vault write ssh/roles/clientrole @signer-clientrole.hcl
```

However, when I want to sign a certificate with my username entered in the "principals" web form I receive an Error that the principal does not exist. See image below:

[Sign Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5mL8.png)

I hope my issue became clear. I am using Vault 1.4.2 on Debian 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone struggling with the same issues, I found a solution to the problem.

When configuring the OIDC role, I used `sub` for `bound_subject`, as it was suggested in all corresponding tutorials and I did not question the value. `sub` is some kind of uuid identifying a user in the AD.

So I tried `email` instead and viewed the server.log file and found the following entry:

```
[DEBUG] identity: creating a new entity: alias="id:"..." canonical_id:"..." mount_type:"oidc" mount_accessor:"auth_oidc_..." mount_path:"auth/oidc/" name:"example_user@example.com"...
```

So the value of `bound_subject` is written as a value to `name` at whatever is behind `identity.entity.aliases.$(vault auth list -format=json | jq -r '.["oidc/"].accessor')` (see initial question).

So using now using the email address as principal in the web form works:

[image: Sign Success]

And viewing the Certificate Properties also showed that it worked:

```
ssh-keygen -Lf ssh-cert.pub

ssh-cert-v11.pub:
        Type: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com user certificate
        Public key: RSA-CERT SHA256:...
        Signing CA: RSA SHA256:...
        Key ID: "vault-oidc-example-user@example.com-..."
        Serial: ...
        Valid: from ...
        Principals: 
                example-user@example.com
        Critical Options: (none)
        Extensions: 
                ...
```

Comment: If you accept this answer, the question will be seen as solved, which is helpful for people browsing the site

Comment: How can i determine what `identity.entity.aliases.$(vault auth list -format=json | jq -r '.["oidc/"].accessor')` resolves to on my system?

Comment: This is indeed a very good question. I could not find s.th. like a debug console yet. What is your problem?

Comment: I want to have a role which allows only current user to sign his key. I followed the description above, but keep getting `* <my-username> is not a valid value for valid_principals`. So my guess is, that the expression does not resolve to <my-username>

Comment: Found my problem: my vault-server was running Veriosn 1.3.X, and i think the templating was introduced in 1.4 :-) After upgrading to 1.5.4 it works if i add `allowed_users_template: true` in the role