# Vault SSH PKI - dynamically create "allowed_users" value

Tags: ssh, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

We use OIDC (against Azure AD) to authenticate to Vault. Once authenticated we sign SSH keys with Vault's [SSH Certificate](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/ssh/signed-ssh-certificates) secret engine. Depending on the users' AD Groups we want to set the value of [allowed_users](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/ssh#allowed_users). More particularly, I want to have corresponding AD Groups listed here. I already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773229/vault-ssh-pki-with-oidc-user-as-ssh-principal/62775135#62775135) concerning the username.
Is there any template expression that renders to the users' groups?

S.th. like `{{identity.entity.aliases.<ACCESSOR>.group_names}}`

An alternative would be to create roles for each and every combination of principals I would like to see in SSH Keys. But this means quite some effort and is subject to frequent change.